# Intercept a process during execution time

Tags: c#, winapi

I am developing an application must intercept a process and prevent it from executing fully until a users credentials are verified. I have no idea where to go or to begin researching.

I know it is possible as Kaspersky AntiVirus has something similar - when you launch application A, it checks its white list for application A and if it is not found, it halts execution and prompts the user with a question - only when the user clicks Allow, execution resumes.

Comment: How is the process started. I would go for a launcher scenario where the application can only be started through you're launcher.

Comment: @CodingBarfield - The process is started when the user executes it. Would you be able to post a link to some reading material for the Launcher Scenario?